# Import sql file into MYSQL database using MYSQLAdmin or php

Tags: php, mysql, import

I am trying to import a sql file into a database hosted by my web host via its MYSQL administration program mysqladmin. Mysqladmin has an Import button that from what I can tell just runs some sql code. When I go through the steps, however, it give me the errors below. (I tried getting help from customer support but they don't support this.)

Here is what appears in pink in the error box:

```
Error
SQL query:

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookquotes` (
`index` VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
`index_id` INT NULL,
`type` VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
`line_id` INT NULL,
`book_name` VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
`speech_number` INT NULL,
`line_number` VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
`speaker` VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
`text_entry` VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
)
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX) NULL,
`index_id` INT NULL,
`type` VARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
`line_id` INT NULL,
`p' at line 2
```

Would appreciate any suggestions in what is wrong with the above SQL (I could run sql to add the table myself in PHP if I can get the right syntax) or otherwise how to import a sql file into a remote database.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: There is no varchar(max) in mysql  where/what dbserver did the .sql file come from??

Comment: The sql file I am trying to add to the remote database was generated by https://app.konbert.com/ from a JSON file.

Comment: I get nothing (literally) from the posted link- are sure this app is for mysql and not sqlserver - in any case if you want to import to mysql you are going to have to transform the .sql file before import.

Comment: Yes, I looked in the sql file and sure enough it has the Max stuff. I'm changing it to text as suggested by Yoleth

Comment: https://konbert.com/convert/json/to/sql

Comment: You probably needed to use https://konbert.com/convert/json/to/mysql instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `MAX` in mysql, see the limitation documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html

If you need very large text column use `TEXT` or instead use `varchar` with reasonable limit.